# Fable-type short story about two-tier society of clay people

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a story I read maybe 20 years ago in a long-lost anthology.  Roughly it was an allegorical fable about a race made of clay.  I recall that some clay folk were of a higher caste than others, but my recollection is quite vague.  New clay folks were fired in ovens, this being their means of reproduction.  The clay folk lived beside a river I think.

I remember that the story made quite an impression on me - perhaps it was a feminist allegory?

I've always had the feeling that it was an Ursula K. LeGuin, but have been unable to find it in lists of her works

I've been trying to find this for years but with no success.

Comment: A quick search for Leguin and "clay people" threw up this novel on google; http://www.fantasyliterature.com/reviews/rocannons-world/

Comment: Not a short-story but similar; http://www.davidbrin.com/kilnpeople.html

Comment: Probably not http://craphound.com/place/Cory_Doctorow_-_Return_to_Pleasure_Island.txt, but throwing it out there.

Comment: None of the above I'm afraid, though Rocannons World is one that I am going to add to my reading list

Comment: Are you certain it was a short? Sounds much like one of Terry Pratchett's books, "Feet of Clay" perhaps, the golems are produced by being baked in ovens and the whole book transpires in a city with a large river running through it. I'm not sure about the hierarchies of the golems though, and there are normal people and other species too, so I don't think this is the answer.

Comment: Definitely a short story, in an anthology with a red cover - just picked it up in a book shop one day, a long time ago